# why this error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding a window to a container

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am trying to make a simple GUI with a button but getting this error.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class GUIClass extends JFrame {

    public static void main (String[] args){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JFrame fm = new JFrame();
        JFrame btn = new JFrame("Click ME");
        btn.setBounds(50, 40, 120, 30);
        fm.add(btn);
        fm.setLayout(null);
        fm.setVisible(true);
        fm.setSize(400, 300);
    }
}
```

Comment: `btn` is a window based class, you can't add windows to windows

Comment: @MadProgrammer than what should i do?

Comment: Maybe start by having a look at [How to make GUIs with Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/), [How to use buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) (I'm guessing) and [Laying out components in a container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 JFrame btn = new JFrame("Click ME");
```

Change it to;

```
JButton btn = new JButton("Click ME");
```

Also don't forget to import javax.swing.JButton;

Also check this out:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html

Comment: Thanks @Nerdic Sapo